# Как с помощью gulp отделить стили для ie от всей таблицы стилей?

Tags: css, sass, sublime-text, gulp, scss

Объясню проблему:
Я пишу код на sass, с помощью переменной `$oldie: 'html.oldie';` назначаю стили для старого ie по ходу кода `#{$oldie} & {display:none;}`

Так вот, когда gulp компилирует scss в css, в потоке кода появляются такие строки: `html.oldie .search_toggle + .search_input { margin-left: 0; }`

Как мне их собрать всех и вынести в отдельный файл не используя ручного труда? Может есть модуль для gulp или какой-то плагин для sublime ?

Есть, конечно, вариант написать самому плагин для sublime, но мне кажется, что не только у меня встречалась подобная проблема

Comment: можно попробовать анализировать содержимое файла в потоке, вырезать искомое и сохранять в другой файл.

Answer (score 0):

Можно только создать отдельный таск для генерации в IE, а стили прописывать в отдельном файле.